# What does tomcat do when session expires?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

What does tomcat do when session expires?

Does it set the session object invalidated?

Does it unlink all references to the session object so that I may not be able to get the expired session object by calling `request.getSession(false)` ?

I'm using Servlet 2.5 spec. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no internal session garbage collector thread. Session are removed during `getSession()` invocations.

If `request.getSession()` is invoked and the session is no longer valid (its idle time is greater than `maxInactiveInterval`) then internal [`expire()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-catalina/7.0.42/org/apache/catalina/session/StandardSession.java#754) method will be called. This method removes session from the [`Manager`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-catalina/7.0.42/org/apache/catalina/Manager.java#Manager) and fires appropriate events on the [`HttpSessionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html).

One can manually invalidate the session using its `invalidate()` method, which is a wrapper for the `expire()`.

Comment: Note that `invalidate()` calls `expire()`.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat (and every other container) will call `HttpSession.invalidate()`

[From the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#invalidate%28%29):

> Invalidates this session then unbinds any objects bound to it.

Afterwards, `request.getSession(false)` will return `null`.

Related:

- [Best Practice: Releasing and invalidating HTTP sessions](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/bestpractices/releasing_and_invalidating_httpsessions.html)